# What is the inverse of: f(vector) = vector*squareMagnitude

Tags: math, vector, magnitude

I believe the square magnitude of a 3 component vector is: (x*x + y*y + z*z). If you multiply a vector by its square magnitude, is there a function that you can perform to obtain the original vector?

Lets take original vector3 A = (Ax, Ay, Az).
The final vector3 B = A*(Ax*Ax + Ay*Ay + Az*Az).

Now, is there a function of B that will return A?

Thank you!

I originally found that the dot product of a Vector with itself equals the vectors square magnitude. However, I also read that the inverse of dot product is impossible because of many solutions. Still, with the two qualifiers (1: the dot product is between a vector and itself, 2: the final vector's components are linearly related to the original vector's corresponding components) there may be enough to restrict to one possible solution.

Comment: Should be a https://math.stackexchange.com/ question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get squared magnitude of `B`. Note that result `SMB` is equal to magnitude of `A` in the sixth power (or cube of `SMA=squareMagnitude(A)`).

```
B = bx +       by +       bx = 
    ax * SMA + ay * SMA + az * SMA

SMB = B.dot.B = ax^2 * SMA^2 + ay^2 * SMA^2 + az^2 * SMA^2 = 
                SMA^2*(ax^2 + ay^2 + az^2) = 
                SMA^2 * SMA = 
                SMA^3
```

So you can get `squareMagnitude(A)` as cube root of `SMB` and extract components of `A`

```
 SMA = SMB^(1/3) = pow(SBB, 1./3)    
 ax = bx / SMA
 ay = by / SMA
 az = bz / SMA
```

P.S. It is interesting - what operations do provide `B` value?

Concerning the second question - not very readable in comments, so I've added this:

```
A/(1+SMA)=B   square it
SMA/(1+2*SMA+SMA^2)=SMB
SMA = SMB+2*SMA*SMB+SMA^2*SMB
SMA^2*SMB+SMA*(2*SMB-1)+SMB = 0 
D = 4*SMB^2-4*SMB+1-4*SMB^2= 1-4*SMB  
   D should be positive, so B magnitude should be small 
SMA = (1-2*SMB + Sqrt(1-4*SMB)) /(2*SMB)
    the second solution with minus is definitely negative, so omit it
 and finally with known SMA
A = B * (1 + SMA)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly. However, I am afraid my question did not present my challenge correctly. I actually need to get vector A from vector B when B is defined as: B = A / (1.0 + SMA). I am really hoping that the original vector A can be derived from B! Any thoughts?

Comment: Sadly no, in  case of B = A / (1.0 + SMA) it is not possible to get A if SMA value is not known

Comment: If my math is correct, is would appear that in the last mentioned relationship, SMA/(1+SMA)^2 = SMB. Thus, you would get a quadratic relationship that make SMA = -(2SMB - 1) +- sqrt((2SMB-1)^2 - 4(SMB)^2) in the numerator and 2SMB in the denominator. With this definition of SMA, you should be able to plug it into A = B*SMA to get A in terms of B alone. You would just have 2 possible answers for each component I guess, but maybe another function or rule could rule out the undesired answer

Comment: Sorry, plug the definition of SMA into A = B(1 + SMA), not A = B*SMA

Comment: Indeed, I just tried out this approach in c# and it works

Comment: Nice! I added math in answer for the sake of completeness

Comment: Thank you! The purpose for reversing the operation is related to geometric transformations in non-euclidean space. It is for computer graphics.

Answer (score 1):

B = (|A|^2) A so |B| = |A|^3, so A = B/(|A|^2) = B/(|B|^(2/3)).